# Cannot create Pycharm launcher on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, pycharm, launcher

I am trying to create a command line launcher for pycharm. My OS is Linux Mint. I am doing this by going Tools > Create Command-line launcher and following the default steps. However, I receive this error:

`pycharm launcher script creation failed unsupported os/desktop: linux/gnome`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint... what?

Assuming that you are running `Linux Mint 19 Tara bionic beaver`

---

I would recommend a `snap` installation

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

Once finished, run `pycharm-community`